# JavaScript not firing on multiple class elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having some trouble getting JavaScript code to fire for select HTML tables on a page. The idea is to have all tables with the class stripe_table be styled by a few JavaScript functions.

The JavaScript fires with this in the HTML:

```
<body onload=searchPage()>
```

The searchPage function looks for all elements with the stripe_table class  and passes them to some styling functions.

```
function searchPage() {
    var table = document.getElementsByClassName('stripe_table');
    //Pass the table nodelist to the styling functions.
    styleTable(table);
    hoverColorChange(table);
}
```

Currently it's only styling one table out of the two on the page.

The styleTable function is below:

The hoverColorChange function is below:

Comment: You haven't given enough information to find the error..  What does `styleTable()` and `hoverColorChange()` do?  What does `console.log(table.length)` output?

Comment: Thanks, OP, for editing to include a basic outline of your helper functions. Seeing their actual code, however, would help a great deal more.

Answer (score 5):

Note that `document.getElementsByClassName` returns **a set of elements** which have all the given class names. You should be certain that your `styleTable` and `hoverColorChange` functions iterate through that returned collection (by means of a `for` loop or perhaps `Array.filter`).

http://devdocs.io/dom/document.getelementsbyclassname

I would recommend you rename your variable to be plural, by the way, to make it more clear that it is a collection (`tables` not `table`).

**ADDENDUM:**

Thanks for posting your complete code. Pasting it into Sublime Text 3 with [JSLinter](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3) enabled, I'm getting several warnings, including:

- Variables (e.g. `tr` and `anchors`) used out of their declared scopes.
- Use of `==` rather than `===`.
- Missing semicolons.
- Functions defined within `for` loops.

Fix those, and give it another run.

Comment: I think [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) would be more useful than `Array.filter` :-)

Comment: Best answer I can provide, given the current scope of information provided in the question. You're right, though. It would help a lot to see the actual code for OP's styling functions.

Comment: I would post my code for the styling functions but this code is for an assignment. Just didn't want others to find the post and use my code :)

Comment: Surely your school does not emphasize competition over collaboration? ;)